# How to find file associated with resource (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image, resources, toolbar

I need to edit a toolbar image, but the Image Collection Editor doesn't give a clue WHERE it resides.  No file name or resource ID.  How can I find this image?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Some resources are stored separately in the form's .resx file.

Comment: Hi, I' having the same issue, can you point me the file's location? Thank you.